# libc.so.6 erros, how to bundle a qt5 app to centos 6.5?

Tags: qt, bundle, libc

I'm working on centos 7 qt5 and I need to make my app run in centos 6.5

I'm getting libc erros because libc in centos 6.5 is older:

```
/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found
```

I have compiled qt from souce static and I'm using those link flags:

```
CONFIG += c++11 -static
LIBS+= -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE+= -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

but still and I run ldd on the app I get that:

```
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6
```

why is qt still link libc dynamicly?

what are the other options to bundle a qt5 to centos 6.5 without install qt5 on centos 6.5?

thanks in advance!

Luiz

Comment: [This answer says linking libc statically is not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304531/compiling-with-static-libgcc-static-libstdc-still-results-in-dynamic-depende#26306630). Maybe it would be easier to just compile on centos 6.5, if only for deployment?

Comment: I could do that but to install qt 5 in centos 6.5 I need to updgrade gcc and libc, so I still have the same issue when I try to run the app in machine without qt5, right?