# C++ stream becomes bad if called in multiple shared libs and libstdc++ static linking is enabled

Tags: c++, fstream, iostream, static-linking, dlopen

I compiled 2 shared libs with --static-libstdc++ enabled.

The 2 shared libs have the same function `f`, which just outputs a string and an integer to stdout.

Main program will load the 2 shared libs using `dlopen`, and call the `f` in it using `dlsym`.

However, the second loaded shared lib failed to output the integer and the C++ stream `cout` becomes `bad & fail`.

> ADD: After discussion, I know this is normal... However, I want to change my question to: what implementation of libstdc++ caused this issue? Is there any shared global state? I think if there is no shared global state, it shouldn't be a problem. I wrote the similar program in Windows by static linking to VCRuntime and using LoadLibrary, and it works normally. So why libstdc++ is designed like this?

---

The following is the code for 2 shared libraries. (They share the same code)
They will just `cout` a string and a integer.

```cpp
// dll.cpp

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" void f()
{
    cout << "hi" << 1 << endl;

    bool is_eof = cout.eof();
    bool is_fail = cout.fail();
    bool is_bad = cout.bad();

    cout.clear();

    cout << endl;
    cout << "eof: " << to_string(is_eof) << endl;
    cout << "fail: " << to_string(is_fail) << endl;
    cout << "bad: " << to_string(is_bad) << endl;
}
```

This is the main program, which loads the shared libs and calls their `f` functions.

```cpp
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

using fn_t = void(void);

void call_f_in_dll(const char *dll_path)
{
    auto dll = dlopen(dll_path, RTLD_LAZY);
    assert(dll);
    fn_t *fn = (fn_t *)dlsym(dll, "f");
    assert(fn);
    fn();
    dlclose(dll);
}

int main()
{
    call_f_in_dll("./libmydll.so");

    cout << endl;

    call_f_in_dll("./libmydll2.so");

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the CMakeLists.

```
# CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project (TestGCC)

add_link_options(-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++)

add_library(mydll SHARED dll.cpp)
add_library(mydll2 SHARED dll.cpp)

add_executable (main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main dl)
```

And the output is:

```
hox@HOX-PC:~/repos/test-gcc/out$ ./main
hi1

eof: 0
fail: 0
bad: 0

hi
eof: 0
fail: 1
bad: 1
```

> Notice the second part, there is no `1` after `hi` and `fail & bad` become `1`.

[image: result]

You can checkout the code here: https://github.com/xuhongxu96/dlopen-iostream-issue

Comment: What happens if you don't `dlclose()` the libs?

Comment: @SimonKraemer I've tried and nothing changed...

Comment: In [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160313071116/http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/06/static-libstdc/) the author mentions that "(...)  for this to work reliably you must not use dynamically loaded C++ code, including code loaded with dlopen."

Comment: What is the reason that you want/need to use  `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++`? (Just to be sure that you really need that)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linking libstdc++ statically: any gotchas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636513/linking-libstdc-statically-any-gotchas)

Comment: I just want to distribute our lib easier by reducing dependencies. The lib may be used in compliant server machines, and deploying binaries on it requires complex procedures. Of course I can use dynamic linking and copy the libstdc++.so with the lib. But I really curious about the issue.

Comment: There are various posts about that topic with somehow contradicting conclusions. (like [Compiling with -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ still results in dynamic dependency on libc.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304531) and [Linking libstdc++ statically: any gotchas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636513)). I would probably go with the suggestion of [this answer to Linking libstdc++ statically: any gotchas?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14082540) `[…]Another option (and the one I prefer) is to deploy the newer libstdc++.so alongside your application […]`

Comment: @pptaszni Thanks for your info. If I understood right, the article says there are some shared global states in libstdc++ and if I use dlopen to load 2 static-linked shared libs, they will conflict which could cause issues.

Comment: @HongxuXu `[…]if I use dlopen to load 2 static-linked shared libs, they will conflict which could cause issues[…]` yes.

Comment: @t.niese Thanks for info. I decide to continue using static linking now. But I'm still curious about the libstdc++ implementation of iostream/fstream and want to figure out what exactly caused the issue (maybe conflict shared global state?)

Comment: I implemented the same pattern in Windows using MSVC by static linking to VC runtime and LoadLibrary to load the DLLs. It works normally. That's why I'm curious about the implementation :)

Comment: @OP: That is perfectly normal, the reason is the multiple libstdc++. (Also your main program has to linked with libstdc++.)

Comment: Can you try making dll global symbols local visible with auto dll = dlopen(dll_path, RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL) ?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond Thanks for answer. But If libstdc++ can be designed as an isolated lib, I don't think multiple instances could be a problem. I wonder what exactly the design of it makes it impossible.

Comment: @HongxuXu `cout` needs to somehow pass the data to its destination, depending on what functionality it uses, the `stdlib` might use an indirection over another system feature or dynamically linked library or needs to manage the  _"connection"_ to the console directly. If it manages the _"connection"_ to the console directly then the two static linked stdlibs would try to use the same socket/stream, which might conflict.

Comment: @StPiere Thanks for info. Unfortunately, I just tried and it doesn't work.

Comment: @Hongxu: ok. What I would try next would be RTLD_NODELETE and/or RTLD_NOSHARE. Unfortunately have no enough time right now to try out by myself.

Comment: Also if parts of your programs were compiled with different compiler-settings (e.g. with/without pthreads) they won't be compatible.

Comment: @t.niese Really thanks for the answer. I really want the detailed explanation like yours. I've been debugging for a while and found it actually threw `bad_cast` at `const __num_put_type& __np = __check_facet(this->_M_num_put);` (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.3/libstdc++/api/a01401_source.html#l00072)

Comment: @HongxuXu I don't know the exact reason why `cout` fails in you case, I just wanted to illustrate why such a problem could occur. Another thing that could be problematic, is to pass objects of a library `A` to or between dynamically linked libraries that link statically against that library `A`. E.g. if the library `A` somehow manages parts of their state internally (like a thread pool, or if memory allocation was changed in some way).

Comment: "if I use dlopen to load 2 static-linked shared libs, they will conflict" They will not conflict with each other, but they WILL conflict with the state in your main program, possibly unless you use `RTLD_DEEPBIND`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Thanks for tips. I've tried DEEPBIND but it doesn't work. However, I finally made it work by using `dlmopen`, which provides more strict isolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way to resolve the issue in Linux (GNU Extensions).

Use `dlmopen` which provides better isolation btw objects.

```cpp
auto dll = dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM, dll_path, RTLD_LAZY);
```

Great thanks for all commenters!

> Still welcome to explain the details about what the conflict states are.

Comment: https://manpages.debian.org/testing/manpages-dev/dlmopen.3.en.html#dlmopen()_and_namespaces

Comment: Possible uses of dlmopen() are plugins where the author of the plugin-loading framework can't trust the plugin authors and does not wish any undefined symbols from the plugin framework to be resolved to plugin symbols. Another use is to load the same object more than once. Without the use of dlmopen(), this would require the creation of distinct copies of the shared object file. Using dlmopen(), this can be achieved by loading the same shared object file into different namespaces.